# Why $S_{\gamma'(0)}(J(0))=0$ for the geodesic sub-manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from [do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry](https://library.lol/main/0A30B69FEAD8267DB0705B4F81764346), I don't know how to show the red line. The $S$ is shape operator, assuming local extension of $\gamma'(0)$ is $N$ which normal to $M$, then
$$
S_{\gamma'(0)} J(0) = -(\nabla_{J(0)}N)^T
$$
where $\nabla$ is connection of $M$, and $T$ means the tangential component.

**What I get from Deane:** Since his mark is a little confused, I'll explain the mark first. Let $\gamma(t)$ is the geodesic in picture below. $f(s,t)$ is the extand of $\gamma(t)$ such that
$$
f(0,t) =\gamma(t),~~~ \partial_t f(0,0) =\gamma'(0),~~~
\partial_t f(s,0) \bot\sum\nolimits_\epsilon
$$
Then, $J(t)=\partial_s f(0,t)$ is Jacobi field along $\gamma(t)$, and to be less precise, there is
$$
S_{\gamma'(0)} J(0) = -(\nabla_{J(0)}\partial_t f(s,0))^T
$$
For showing $S_{\gamma'(0)} J(0)=0$, $\forall v\in T_{\gamma(0)}\sum\nolimits_\epsilon$, there is
$$
\langle S_{\gamma'(0)} J(0), v\rangle = 
\langle
-(\nabla_{J(0)}\partial_t f(s,0))^T, v
\rangle
=
\langle
-\nabla_{J(0)}\partial_t f(s,0), v
\rangle
=
\langle
\partial_t f(s,0), \nabla_{J(0)} v
\rangle
$$
Then, I feel there is  $\nabla_{J(0)} v\in T_{\gamma(0)}\sum\nolimits_\epsilon$. If so, there is $\langle S_{\gamma'(0)} J(0), v\rangle = 0$. But I can't explain why $\nabla_{J(0)} v\in T_{\gamma(0)}\sum\nolimits_\epsilon$.

> [image]

Comment: Extend $\gamma$ to a family of unit speed geodesics $\gamma_t$ normal to $\Sigma$ and observe that the $\gamma'_t(0)$ is the unit normal at $\gamma_t(0)$, i.e., the Gauss map.

Comment: @Deane Sorry, I don't see what you mean. I know what is Gauss map, but I don't know how to connect it with the red line.  Could you tell me more about it? Thanks.

Comment: On one hand, $J=\partial_t\gamma$. On the other hand, $\gamma_t’(0)$ is a unit normal to $\Sigma$. Therefore if you differentiate it with respect to $t$, you get the shape operator. I’ll let you fill in the details.

Comment: I don't recall what I had in mind originally. I now believe that this equation follows from the fact that the surface $\Sigma$ is the image of the exponential map centered at $\gamma(0)$ restricted to a tangent hyperplane. This implies that the shape operator of $\Sigma$ at $\gamma(0)$ is zero for any vector tangent to $\Sigma$, not just $J(0)$.

Comment: @Deane  I don't know. I have get the red line, but I need $J'(0)=0$. So, I feel  you may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the story. I'm pretty sure it's all in the book somewhere.

First, let $\Sigma \subset M$ be any hypersurface. For each $x \in \Sigma$, let $\nu(x)$ be a unit normal to $\Sigma$ such that $\nu$ always points to the same side of $\Sigma$. This, of course, is the Gauss map. Recall that given any $X \in T_x\Sigma$, the shape operator is defined to be
$$ S(X) = \nabla_X\nu. $$

You can then define the exponential map from $\Sigma$ (rather than from a point) to be the map
$$ E: \Sigma\times(-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow M, $$
where for each $x \in \Sigma$, the curve
$$ \gamma_x(t) = E(x,t) $$ is a unit speed geodesic.
Given $x \in \Sigma$ and $X \in T_x\Sigma$, let $c: (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow \Sigma$ be a curve such that $c(0)=x$ and $c'(0) = X$. Consider the $1$-parameter family of geodescs
\begin{align*}
C: (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times(-\delta,\delta) &\rightarrow M\\
(s,t) &\mapsto E(c(s),t).
\end{align*}
Then
$$
J(t) = \left.\partial_sC(s,t)\right|_{s=0}
$$
is a Jacobi field along the geodesic $\gamma_x$ such that
$$ J(0) = c'(0) = X $$
and
\begin{align*}
J'(0) &= \nabla_{\partial_t C}\partial_sC(0,0)\\
&= \nabla_{\partial_sC(0,0)}\partial_tC(0,0)\\
&= \nabla_X\nu\\
&= S(X).
\end{align*}

Now let
$$ T = \{ v\in T_xM\ :\ \langle v,\gamma_x'(0)\rangle = 0  \}$$
and let $\Sigma$ be the hypersurface parameterized by the map
\begin{align*}
T &\rightarrow M\\
v &\mapsto \exp_x(v).
\end{align*}
In particular, for each $X \in T_x\Sigma$, the constant speed geodesic
$$
c(s) = \exp_x sX
$$
is in $\Sigma$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\langle X, S(X)\rangle &= \langle c'(0), \nabla_{c'(0)}\nu\rangle\\
&= \left.\partial_s\right|_{s=0}\langle c'(s),\nu(c(s))\rangle
- \langle \nabla_{c'}c',\nu\rangle\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
Since this holds for all $X \in T_x\Sigma$, it follows that
$$ S(v) = 0 $$
for all $v \in T_x\Sigma$.

Comment: I didn't really read books when I was younger, so I probably don't remember what I read. The reason I think you might be wrong is because I'm ignoring the fact that codimension of $\sum$  is one.  Thanks your detail answer.